# Jquery Date PIcker, if todays date, perform a dialog

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am wanting to set this jquery date picker to throw an alert / dialog if the date selected is todays date. I am using smarty, thats the date function you see. However when I input todays date,  the script will still not return the dialog that represents today. Here is the script:

```
$("#sanctionDateStart").datepicker({
    altField: "#sanctionDateStart_hidden", 
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    minDate: new Date()
}).datepicker("setDate", "{$data.sanctionDateStart}").change(function () {
    $('#sanctionDateEnd').datepicker('option', 'minDate',
    $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    if ($(this).datepicker('getDate') == '{date("m/d/Y", $smarty.now)}'){
        alert ('Todays Date');  
    }
    else {
        alert ('Not Todays Date');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Datepicker onSelect instead of .change

```
 $('selector').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        //Do your thing here
        //date hold selected date
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The date picker returns a `Date` object, which can't be equal to a string. You need to convert the string from Smarty into a JS `Date`. See the [`Date` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to see how to do that.